# How do I automatically rotate and move a camera mapped texture?

Tags: shaders, camera, shader-nodes, vector

I have this cylinder, I'd like the texture that has been projected onto it to move and rotate along with the shape. Here's a mockup of what I'm envisioning, made possible by animating the texture instead:

[image: 3]

Here's what I have so far:

[image: 1]

As you can see the texture doesn't rotate with the shape. When moving the shape the texture doesn't move with it.

Current shader nodes:

[image: 2]

The "Combine XYZ"-node holds three expressions for the X, Y and Z quaternion angles of the cylinder. I don't know how to translate these into the angle I need.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Simple question, why don't you project using for example a camera as projector and with the modifier UV project on your object, you move the camera to the desired projection location and you can "lock" the transforms by parenting the camera to your object.

Comment: @softyodayoann It may be a simple question but it helped me with my problem a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to softyoda yoann's suggestion to use the UV project modifier I tried to use object mapping instead of window/camera mapping. Here's what I came up with:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I've attached the cylinder to an armature with a single bone. Then I've created an empty arrow object and parented it to the camera, meaning its local space is camera space. On this arrow object I've applied the following constraints:

[image: 3]

(C_Cylinder is the cylinder's armature.) With these constraints the arrow object follows the bone's location, aligns the Y axis with the bone's tail and points the Z axis towards the camera, in that order. Then I used object mapping instead of camera/window mapping:

[image: 4]

Here's another screenshot that hopefully shows the difference better between this method and regular UV mapping:

On the left the new object mapping is being used, on the right is a regular UV unwrap. On the left example you can see that the thickness and distance between the lines remains the same, on the right example you can see that they get thinner and closer together as the cylinder's faces face more away from the camera, which is normal. With window mapping the effect would be stronger because it would use a simple flat projection, but this is good enough for now.

[image: 5]

Comment: Glad I could help, I would have made a proper answer if I knew that this was what you needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use object properties to counter the rotation and movement of the object. For the simplest case, position the camera in top orthographic view, rotate the object around Z axis and move it (doesn't matter if you move on Z, since orthographic):

[image]

[image]

This doesn't implement scaling but you get the idea… It gets much trickier if you want to go outside the ortographic and Z axis rotation… So much so that first you need to even realize what you want to happen when a face invisible in the "basis state" (the state from which a snapshot of camera space texture is taken) is rotated to become visible - should it be just black, or a stretched color?

Comment: I think the idea was that there would be no "bases state" so that the texture would just get reprojected to the parts of the object that become visible because of perspective shift(or Z rotation).

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys there must be base state if the texture is supposed to follow the object even though it moves in the camera space 

Comment: I thought camera space could just get transformed the same way the object is then the parts that rotate or are revealed by changing perspective just get projection from camera. Projection happens real time and the base state is only location, rotation and scale. It's hard to think of a use case for this to be honest.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yes, but if you transform camera space by rotating it by 90° around either X or Y camera axis, you effectively squeeze yourself to a single dimension. Unless you want to use triplanar or otherwise non-2D mapping of the Image Texture…

Answer (score 2):

Camera texture coordinates are meant for exactly what you show as current result. They are not meant for situations when you need the textures to move with the object.

If you need the texture to move with the object, you should project UVs from camera position and use UV texture coordinates.

You can do that by entering Edit Mode, selecting all(<kbd>a</kbd>) and hitting <kbd>u</kbd> for UV Mapping menu and choosing Project from View while looking through the camera:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I understand what camera mapping and window mapping is for, but I'm trying to get more out of it. By mapping it this way it appears more flat than when using a regular UV map. That flatter look, that's what I'm after.

Comment: What do you mean? It's identically flat, only the scale might differ. You might get some distortions depending on the geometry. Those can be avoided increasing the density of the geometry. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Sure, it's best explained with [an image.](https://i.imgur.com/7nZVAOe.png) On the left I've used window mapping and on the right I've used a regular UV, I've also increased the FOV for clarity.
With the window mapping the distance between the lines and the line thickness remains roughly the same.
With the regular UV mapping the lines get closer together and become thinner as the angle of the shape relative to the viewer changes. This is normal and not what I want.
I hope I explained that well, but if not I think you can see the difference between the two approaches. Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, I am unable to replicate this with still objects so I am not sure if I understand it fully, but I definitely see now how the perspective can become a problem with the object animated.

Comment: You would probably need to know difference in camera and object locations and rotations and this might also depend on camera lens focal length and distance between camera and object. Scripted drivers are probably the way to go. But that's too much for me I'm afraid- I give up :D .